# Router not working when adding vitejs v2 to Vue v3

Tags: vue.js, vite

An app that has been using `webpack` for the dev server should now use `vite`. Everything seems to be working fine (and fast) with the exception of routes. These are simply ignored and only the content of `App.vue` is rendered.

This is `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "mode",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.1.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "vite": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3"
  }
}
```

The central `index.html` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `src/main.ts` the `router` is loaded:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

That router is defined in `src/router/index.ts`:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import SomePage from '@/views/SomePage.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [{
      path: '/some',
      name: 'Some',
      component: SomePage
  }]
})

export default router
```

The (never shown) `src/views/SomePage.vue` is:

```html
<template>
  <div class="section">
    Some content on some page.
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is the (always shown) `App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3 + Vite" />
</template>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>
```

With this `src/components/HelloWorld.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <p>
    Fancy text.
  </p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

defineProps({
  msg: String
})
</script>
```

I would expect http://localhost:3000/some to show the content of `SomePage.vue`, but only the content of `App.vue` is rendered, regardless of the route used.

Pointers to what I'm missing here and why the fine route is ignored are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a router-view to go to the page routed.

If you want SomePage to be part of App.vue just do so by

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <router-view />
  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3 + Vite" />
</template>
```